# Where to put CSS files in Grails apps?

Tags: css, grails

First Grails (2.3.6) app here. Trying to add a custom CSS file to my `views/index.gsp`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside my `grails-app` directory, where the `views` subdir lives, I would have expected to see a `resources` or `css` directory, but don't see anything. So I ask: **where do I place `main.css` so that it's available to `index.gsp` at runtime?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your css should not go under grails-app/views.  It should be under web-app/css/.  Then you can do something like this in your GSP...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
```

Comment: If you name it `main` it won't work because it will be overwritted with grails `main.css` file.

Comment: "If you name it main it won't work because it will be overwritted with grails main.css file." @user230137 You can name it anything you like.  If you want to replace the existing main.css you can do that.  If you want a file in addition to the existing main.css you can do that.